# How do I create a zero-length file using the Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, file-management

I'm using Ubuntu for the first time and I have to create a directory and then create a zero-length file inside that directory. After that, apparently I have to do a long listing of the file to show it has zero bytes. I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mkdir directory_name
 cd directory_name
 touch file_name_to_create
 ls -l file_name_to_create
```

If the file already exists, then `touch` will *not* change its length to zero. But if the file does not exist, then it will be created with zero length.